# Will wget -k still convert links to relative paths if wget is stopped prematurely?

Tags: wget

I am running wget on a site that (I have come to realize) has two languages - and duplicate pages for each language. I've already got the content in English, so I'd like to stop wget from downloading anything more. I specified the -k switch when I ran it, so will it convert the links to relative links as usual if I stop wget before it's done completely downloading everything? Or will it simply stop?

(There's another question on the StackExchange network that addresses forcing wget to convert links on already downloaded content by running

```
wget -nc -k [previous options] [previous url]
```

but timestamps were accidentally turned off so that's not an option.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

The -k option is not applied until the download has completed.

If wget is cancelled (ie, ctrl+c) then the -k option will not be invoked.

You can see this when wget completes, the last steps is the conversion of the links.

It tells you at the end, how many .html files it converted. Their timestamps also get updated during this process.

**UPDATE:**
Try making use of the -R option to exlude the files that are in a different language. But this only works if the files have something that makes them uniformly unique.

Try for example:

```
-R*_en*.htm*
```

That would exclude files that end in .htm or .html and that have the _en somewhere in their path. I use an underscore or something that would *buffer* the "en" portion because I do not want to exclude files that simply contain an "en".

But this only works if their is consistency in the file naming.

Comment: Aargh. Thanks for the quick answer (though it's not the one I wanted...).

Comment: @kathryn lol. Like a genie, you get what you ask for. I've updated the answer to show how the -R (--reject) option could work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; much appreciated (even if only for the future, heh). The thing is that wget is downloading right now - you can't modify the job as it's running, can you?

Comment: No, unfortunately you can't, but, if you want to cancel, go ahead, and when you rerun wget also add the -nc (no clobber) option. This will prevent files you've already downloaded from being downloaded again.