# Using wget or another command, how to download now but convert links later?

Tags: wget, html

The useful option `wget --convert-links` or `wget -k` makes "links in downloaded HTML or CSS point to local files." It makes two passes:

- Pass 1: download files.
- Pass 2: convert links.

I want to do pass 1 now and pass 2 later. I want to invoke the two passes separately. I want `wget` to stop after pass 1, let me do some stuff, and only then continue with pass 2. I just want to convert links as a separate command, whether the command is `wget` or something else. How, please?

And if `wget` won't do this, then is there a Perl module, Python module or the like that will?

(For reference: [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41766/18202) partly answers my question. [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/177330/18202) is similar, but its answer seems to fail.  At any rate, neither gives something that actually works as far as I can tell.)

Comment: I gather that the current version of `wget` lacks the feature I need. Therefore, I might [try to add the feature](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=847216) to the next version of `wget`.

Comment: It look like a doable job for htttrack: https://www.httrack.com/html/fcguide.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this question was actually answered in this other [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7378), but it is outdated, so here is the current solution:

It involves passing your local directory after your 'Pass 1' to `wget` making it believe it's a website. This is easily done with some short Python code invoking [SimpleHTTPRequestHandler](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/http.server.html#http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler), and then you re-`wget` from localhost with the appropriate options.

Something along [these lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39801780/6347817) can work:

```
import http.server
import socketserver
import os

PORT = 8000 # optional, can be changed

web_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path), 'web') # change path to your local files here if needed, like '/home' or 'C:\\tmp' on Windows
os.chdir(web_dir)

Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
print("serving at port", PORT)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

then your `wget` can be called on `http://localhost:8000`

Comment: I added `<!-- language: lang-python-->` and the extra line after that is required to have Python formatting, but the formatting doesn't show up. If somebody can edit/fix that'd be great :) (I guess adding the Python tag to the question would do the job, but not sure it's the best approach here)